# What's wrong with compact-open topology on the space of maps?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry

Given a smooth vector bundle $E$ with *non-compact* base, let
$\Gamma(E)$ be the space of $C^\infty$ sections equipped with *compact-open* $C^\infty$-topology.

1. I have heard that $\Gamma(E)$ is not locally-contractible. Why not?
2. Is $\Gamma(E)$ contractible? Visibly any section can be joined to the zero section by "straight line", doesn't this prove that $\Gamma(E)$ is contractible?
3. Is it true that every convex subset of $\Gamma(E)$ is contractible? The argument of 2 seems to apply, but then it seems plausible that each section has an arbitrary small convex neighborhood, contradicting 1.

CLARIFICATION: One source of "rumor 1" is the book "The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis" freely available 
 [here](http://www.ams.org/publications/online-books/surv53-index). On page
429 one reads: "Unfortunately, for non-compact $M$, the space $C^\infty(M, N)$ is not locally contractible in the compact-open $C^\infty$-topology". Another source is the discussion in Hirsch's book in the beginning of Chapter 2, which says "It can be shown that
$C^\infty(M, N)$ has very nice features, e.g. it has a complete metric, and a countable base; if $M$ is *compact*, it is locally contractible and $C^r(M, \mathbb R^n)$ is a Banach space for $2\le r<\infty$".

Thus I assumeed that in general, if $M$ is non-compact, then the space $\Gamma(E)$ is not (or maybe just need not be?) locally contractible. Also I am uncertain whether $C^\infty(M, \mathbb R^n)$ or $\Gamma(E)$ is a topological vector space, is it really? There seems to be a sequence of semi-norms giving these spaces a structure of Frechet spaces, but then they must be locally convex, hence locally contractible. Obviously, I am missing something.

In response to comments I ask a more specific question.

**Question.** Let $T_{r,s}(M)$ denote the space of $C^\infty$-smooth $(r,s)$-tensors on a connected non-compact $C^\infty$ manifold $M$. For $k$ with $2\le k\le \infty$, give $T_{r,s}(M)$ the weak $C^k$-topology as in Hirsch's book (roughly for $k$ finite we require that given $\epsilon>0$ and compact subset $K$ all derivatives up to $k$ are $\epsilon$-close over $K$, and for $k=\infty$ we take the union of all $C^k$-topologies for all finite $k$ under the inclusions $C^\infty\to C^k$). Now I ask

*Is  $T_{r,s}(M)$ a Fréchet space with respect to the weak $C^k$-topology?*

In particular, I want to conclude that $T_{r,s}(M)$ is locally contractible, and any convex subset of $T_{r,s}(M)$ is contractible; I think Fréchet spaces must have this property.

Comment: This is not an answer, but Hirsch's Differential Topology book has a nice chapter on function space topologies.

Comment: Andrew Stacey has started to write up some stuff on the nLab about the "differential topology of mapping spaces" based on a series of lectures he gave at NTNU.  It seems like it might be relevant: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential%20topology%20of%20mapping%20spaces

Comment: And an arXiv paper giving an overview/introduction: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0510097 .  I hope it's relevant.

Comment: As stated, the rumours that you have heard are false.  The simplest case is C^\infty(R,R) - this is sections of the trivial R-bundle over R.  As Sergei hints in his "answer", this is a locally convex topological vector space, and hence contractible.  I suggest that you track down the source of the rumour and get some clarification and then ask a more focussed question.

Comment: Comments on the added quotes: The first is taken from the _introduction_ to a chapter and so should be taken as such.  You should read the whole chapter to discover the meaning behind those words.  I don't have the source for the second quote to hand, but there's still a mistake there: C^\infty(M,R^n) is not a Banach space.  Generally, "compact-open" is a bit misused and so one should always ask "what exactly do you mean?".  In particular, the KM book has quite an extensive discussion on the different topologies and I recommend that you read that and then ask a more focussed question.

Comment: @Andrew, the phrase "$C^\infty(M,\mathbb R^n)$ is a Banach space" came from a typo in my Russian edition of Hirsch's book; it should be $C^r$ with $r$ finite and $>1$.  You are right that I lack understanding of these matters, and this is exactly why I am asking the question. I find the viewpoint of KM book disappointing: the way I see it they say that "compact-open topology" whatever it means is no good, and one needs a modification of Whitney topology to make things work. This is no use to me because for my geometric purposes topology of convergence on compact sets is best. 

Comment: @Willie, I mistakenly typed $C^\infty(M,N)$ instead of $C^\infty(M, \mathbb R^n)$; the latter is a vector space. As for your example with $M=N=S^1$, I want $M$ be non-compact. @Petya, I think if $s$ is any section then $ts$ with $t\in [0,1]$ is a continuous path joining $s$ to the zero section.

Comment: It would help if you could focus your question more precisely, then.  Can you describe an example that you want to know about?  As I said, "compact-open" can mean lots of different things and in infinite dimensions one can often play a little fast-and-loose with the actual topology, so if you could be more specific in your question, we might be able to be more specific in our answers.  In that section, KM had a specific purpose in mind: finding manifold structures.  To do that, they found that the Whitney topology was better. If you have a different application, something else may work better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(For the more specific question)

Yes for $k = \infty$ if $M$ can be exhausted by a countable number of compact sets, no otherwise.  However, the failure is due to a lack of completeness (for $k \ne \infty$) or size issues (if $M$ can't be exhausted) rather than anything else and thus the local contractibility still holds.  Indeed, contractibility holds simply by contracting the vector bundle itself down to the image of the zero section.

The reason is due to the fact that the topology can be described by a family of semi-norms, as Sergei indicates in his comment to his earlier answer, so you get a locally convex topological vector space.  I recommend that you read about these spaces; Schaefer's book is a good place to start (as in Jarchow's but that doesn't seem to be available any more).

(In particular, be wary of saying "union of all $C^k$-topologies"; actually you are taking a projective limit here which means that the space has a $0$-neighbourhood base which is a union of the $0$-neigbourhood bases from each of the $C^k$ topologies, but that doesn't mean that the final topology is the union of all of the $C^k$ topologies.  Simply take a set of point $x_n$ that are "far apart" and put a set $U_n$ about each one so that $U_n$ is open in the $C^n$-topology but not in $C^{n-1}$.  Then $\bigcup U_n$ is open in the $C^\infty$ topology but not in any of the $C^n$-topolgies.)

Comment: Thanks! When you say ''M can be exhausted by a countable number of compact sets'' you must be thinking of non-metrizable manifolds. Any "usual" (i.e. finite dimensional smooth metrizable Hausdorff) manifold certainly has such exhaustion, e.g. the exhaustion by metric balls of any complete Riemannian metric on the manifold; the balls are compact by Hopf-Rinow

Comment: Yes, I was just being extra careful in stating the conditions.  Partly because at the moment I'm thinking about how results like this generalise to things that aren't manifolds.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure it is about *vector* bundles?

Any topological vector space is contractible. Any locally convex topological vector space is locally contractible. This is straightforward from the definitions. The compact-open $C^\infty$ topology is defined by a family of semi-norms and hence locally convex.

In the case of arbitrary fiber bundles, the space of sections can indeed fail to be locally contractible. For example, consider the trivial bundle $\mathbb N\times\{0,1\}$ over $\mathbb N$ (they are 0-dimensional manifolds). The space of sections is not locally contractible (in fact, homeomorphic to the Cantor set). You can build connected examples as well, e.g. consider the trivial circle bundle over a surface with infinitely many handles.

Comment: I am interested in sections of vector bundles because they form a vector space, and hence, $\Gamma(E)$ is more likely to be locally contractible. As you say the space of maps $C^\infty(M, N)$ need not be locally contractible. One specific space I care about is the space of $(r,s)$-tensors on a non-compact manifold.

Comment: For every local trivialization of $E$, every compact subset $K$ of the respective region in $M$ and every positive integer $r$ you define a semi-norm on $\Gamma(E)$ as the coordinate-wise $C^r$ norm of the restriction of a section to $K$. The compact-open $C^\infty$ topology is the topology defined by this family of semi-norms. Thus $\Gamma(E)$ is locally convex topological vector space and hence locally contractible.


Comment: Looks like you are confirming that $\Gamma(E)$ is a Fréchet space. I thought this should be the case, but then I got confused. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite so, you need to be careful if you want a countable family of semi-norms, as explained in Andrew's answer. For local contractibility, this does not matter.



Comment: Not sure I understand the last comment. Andrew, does say that with $C^\infty$ topology $\gamma(E)$ is Fréchet. Indeed, consider semi-norms corresponding to an exhaustion by a countable family of compact sets.   

Comment: I just noted that the particular construction in my first comment is not countable. And cannot be, because it works in the non-metrizable case as well.
